# Problem using environment variables in a VueJs3 + Nuxt3 application

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, vuejs3, nuxt3

I have a Vue.js 3 + Nuxt.js 3 app built, and we have 2 environments: STAGING and PRODUCTION. I am trying to set things up so that our pipeline can build the app every time we push changes to the Staging or Main branches.

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16.13.0 AS build-stage

ARG NUXT_ENV_N_API
ARG NUXT_ENV_SETUP
ARG NUXT_ENV_VR_API

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install
RUN npm run generate

FROM nginx AS runner-stage

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build-stage /app/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

This is my docker-compose-staging.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3005:80"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    environment:
      NUXT_ENV_SETUP: "staging"
      NUXT_ENV_N_API: "staging-url/api"
      NUXT_ENV_VR_API: "staging-v-url/api"
```

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3005:80"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - .:/app
    environment:
      NUXT_ENV_SETUP: "production"
      NUXT_ENV_N_API: "production-url/api"
      NUXT_ENV_VR_API: "production-v-url/api"
```

According to our DevOps guy, these are our environment variables on AWS:

STAGING:

- NUXT_ENV_N_API: staging-url/api
- NUXT_ENV_SETUP: staging
- NUXT_ENV_VR_API: staging-v-url/api

PRODUCTION:

- NUXT_ENV_N_API: production-url/api
- NUXT_ENV_SETUP: production
- NUXT_ENV_VR_API: production-v-url/api

In my nuxt.config.ts file:

```js
import packageJSON from './package.json';

export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: false,
  app: {
    head: {
      charset: 'utf-8',
      viewport: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1',
      link: [
        { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' },
      ]
    }
  },
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      baseURL: process.env.NUXT_ENV_N_API || 'production-url/api',
      vrUrl: process.env.NUXT_ENV_VR_API || 'production-v-url/api',
      setup: process.env.NUXT_ENV_SETUP || 'production',
      version: packageJSON.version
    }
  }
  // ...
})
```

If I log the environment variables using:

```js
console.log('config.public.setup', config.public.setup);
console.log('config.public.baseURL', config.public.baseURL);
console.log('config.public.vrUrl', config.public.vrUrl);
```

Only the default values declared in the nuxt.config.ts file are shown, and not the environment variables.

Do I need to do any other setup to fix this?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've just found the solution. Nuxt uses ARG instead of ENV. So my Dockerfile was changed to:

```
ARG NUXT_ENV_N_API 
ARG NUXT_ENV_SETUP 
ARG NUXT_ENV_VR_API
```

and the docker-compose was changed to:

```
build: 
  context: . 
  dockerfile: Dockerfile 
  args: 
    NUXT_ENV_SETUP: staging 
    NUXT_ENV_N_API: staging-url/api 
    NUXT_ENV_VERUM_API: staging-v-url ...
```

and the "environment:" declaration was removed.

Comment: even thou this works, this also means on build time, the environment has to be assigned. and do we also need to assign ENV NUXT_ENV_N_API=$NUXT_ENV_N_API ?

Comment: i realize on cloudrun, my runtime needed to use from environment variable instead of .env file. therefore ive to fall back to use process.env instead. so took me a long time to realise this:
```
export const useRuntimeEnvConfig = () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || !process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    return useRuntimeConfig()
  }
  return process.env
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to obtain variable during runtime (not build time), then you need to revert to use process.env instead of calling useRuntimeConfig.
For my case, ive this function to fall back when needed:

```
export const useRuntimeEnvConfig = () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || !process.env.NODE_ENV) {
    return useRuntimeConfig()
  }
  return process.env
}
```

It is probably not so elegant but it works. this wold only be use for server side. anything that to be obtained on frontend will need another way.